# Align view center horizontal relative to other view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a couple of views (consider images). One image (bigger one) should be centered horizontally. Other view (smaller) should be to the left of the bigger view, but it should be centered horizontally at the space to the left of bigger view.

One huge restriction: all these views **should be inside the same layout** (I think relative layout suits better for this case).

[image]

But I can't achieve what I need.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems, like this could be done only programmatically.

**Main idea:**

- Create `FrameLayout` and put all the needed views inside it.
- Calculate absolute position on the screen for every view (position of top-left corner for each view). For big view it will be something like: `left = (screenWidth - viewWidth) / 2`, `right = (screenHeight - viewHeight) / 2` (maybe height of statusBar should also be counted).
- Place each view at its position by setting `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` with defined `leftMargin`, `topMargin` – top and left coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this XML...

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/smallView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/smallView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/bigView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/smallView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/smallView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your try. It's more clear to use for inner relative layouts 'align parent left' and 'to left of' center view. Unfortunately, I need to have all views be into the same layout. Seems like I can do this only programmatically